# if null replace with 0, otherwise default value in same column

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In SparkR shell 1.5.0, Created a sample data set:

```
df_test <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(mon = c(1,2,3,4,5), year = c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015)))
df_test1 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(mon1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)))
df_test2 <- join(df_test1, df_test, joinExpr = df_test1$mon1 == df_test$mon, joinType = "left_outer")
```

data set : df_test2

```
+----+----+------+
|mon1| mon|  year|
+----+----+------+
| 7.0|null|  null|
| 1.0| 1.0|2011.0|
| 6.0|null|  null|
| 3.0| 3.0|2013.0|
| 5.0| 5.0|2015.0|
| 8.0|null|  null|
| 4.0| 4.0|2014.0|
| 2.0| 2.0|2012.0|
+----+----+------+
```

**Question:** If there is `null` how can I replace it with `0` in column `df_test2$year` or else use a default value?

The output should look like this,

```
+----+----+------+
|mon1| mon|  year|
+----+----+------+
| 7.0|null|  0   |
| 1.0| 1.0|2011.0|
| 6.0|null|  0   |
| 3.0| 3.0|2013.0|
| 5.0| 5.0|2015.0|
| 8.0|null|  0   |
| 4.0| 4.0|2014.0|
| 2.0| 2.0|2012.0|
+----+----+------+
```

I have used `otherwise/when`, but doesn't work

```
df_test2$year <- otherwise(when(isNull(df_test2$year), 0 ), df_test2$year)
```

It throw ed error,

```
Error in rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'environment'
```

Comment: what exactly is the type of your "null" value? (I don't know SparkR, sorry)

Comment: Try this `df_test2$year[is.null(df_test2$year)] <- 0` Subset your data and "overwrite" the nulls.

Comment: Are you looking for sparkR commands? Problem is easily solved in R, with @Jimbou 's solution or  `setDT(df_test2)[is.null(year),year:=0]`, but will these work for you in spark env?

Comment: Am looking for SparkR commands..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty entries in SparkR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598611/how-to-remove-empty-entries-in-sparkr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used raw SQL `case when` expression to get the answer,

```
df_test3 <- sql(sqlContext, "select mon1, mon, case when year is null then 0 else year end year FROM temp")

showDF(df_test3)
+----+----+------+
|mon1| mon|  year|
+----+----+------+
| 7.0|null|   0.0|
| 1.0| 1.0|2011.0|
| 6.0|null|   0.0|
| 3.0| 3.0|2013.0|
| 5.0| 5.0|2015.0|
| 8.0|null|   0.0|
| 4.0| 4.0|2014.0|
| 2.0| 2.0|2012.0|
+----+----+------+
```

Even though it gives the answer, i am looking for pure sparkR code.

Answer (score 3):

```
df_test2$year <- ifelse(isNull(df_test2$year), 0, df_test2$year)
```

Pure SparkR code that resolves the problem.