# How to replace value by NAN in spark data frame (problem is parallization)

Tags: r, validation, na, sparkr

**Task :**
Let df be a spark data frame. We want to replace a value `n` in `df` by `NA`.

In R I would simply write

```
df[df==n] <- NA
```

Problems / questions :
(as I am new to Spark any comment is welcome)

- What is the equivalent in SparkR to `NA`? 
  I found functions like `isNull` and `isNAN` and I am confused if there are some differences.

**I was able to** do it on one column `col1` using `ifelse`, i.e.

```
df[[col1]] <- ifelse( df[[col1]] == n, NA, df[[x]])
```

but I was not able to "parallize" it.

**I tried :**

```
df <- spark.lapply(colnamed(df), function(x) {ifelse(df[[x]] == n, NA , df[[x]])})
```

but I got the message

> Job aborted due to stage failure

which I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions that may help troubleshoot that error
[Job aborted due to stage failure: Task from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892389/org-apache-spark-sparkexception-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-task-from-app)

[how-to-handle-null-entries-in-sparkr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598611/how-to-handle-null-entries-in-sparkr)
[Add a column full of NAs in Sparkr](http://Add%20a%20column%20full%20of%20NAs%20in%20Sparkr)

[SparkR API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. BUT beside the first link none is dealing with the problem / task, i.e. 

1) how to apply a user defined function in general ?
 sparkr.lapply is for example mentioned in your link to the Sparkr documentation,
 so why does my "code" does not work ? where is my lack in understanding ?

2) as for somebody who is familiar with R I thought there might exists a easy solution for such a specific problem in sparkr

Comment: I don't see 1 being asked anywhere in the question. Read the SparkR API you may find some clues there.